# Reading a GML file in python using a plotly package is not working. how can i handle this?

Tags: python, anaconda, igraph, plotly, gml

My code:

```
import igraph as ig

G=ig.Graph.Read_GML('netscience.gml.txt')
labels=list(G.vs['label'])
N=len(labels)
E=[e.tuple for e in G.es]# list of edges
layt=G.layout('kk') #kamada-kawai layout
type(layt)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:/Users/Soonhyeon/PycharmProjects/Stock/vz1.py", line 3, in <module> G=ig.Graph.Read_GML('netscience.gml.txt')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'netscience.gml.txt'
```

How can I handle this error? I already found a GML file that 'netscience.gml' in web, but I can't find a solution about it. Is the error about igraph packages? Or plotly packages?

Please help, I have studied plotly packages [here](https://plot.ly/python/igraph-networkx-comparison/#comparison).

[image]

Comment: Check current directory. I bet that your file is not here! Did you store it in `C:/Users/Soonhyeon/PycharmProjects/Stock` ? can you `import os; print(os.getcwd())` just to check?